# I want to Implement the Image Searcher using the Tflite Searcher also full implementation with demo images are appreciated

Tags: flutter, image, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

**Error in Terminal**
: tensorflow/lite/util.cc BytesRequired number of elements overflowed.
E/tflite  (31247): Node number 105 (AVERAGE_POOL_2D) failed to prepare.
E/flutter (31247): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: failed precondition

using the Following packages
https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter

I am using the mobile_net v3

and want to implement this but in flutter **https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/image_searcher#run_inference_in_java**

if possible full implementation of it will help

**This Is My Repository Code Part**

```
type here

import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:scankart_application/config/app_images.dart';
import 'package:scankart_application/services/image_utils.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:developer' as l;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

class SearchRepositoryImage {
  late Interpreter _interpreter;
  ImageUtils imageUtils = ImageUtils();

  SearchRepositoryImage() {
    loadModel();
  }

  Future<void> loadModel() async {
    try {
      _interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset(
        "assets/models/lite-model_imagenet_mobilenetv3_small_100_224_feature_vector_5_default_1.tflite",
      );
      _interpreter.allocateTensors();
      l.log("From the Load Model");
      l.log(_interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading the model: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<List<double>> extractImageEmbedding(img.Image image) async {
    // Resize the input image to 224x224 pixels
    img.Image resizedImage = img.copyResize(image, width: 224, height: 224);

    // Convert the resized image to a 1D Float32List.
    Float32List inputBytes = Float32List(1 * 224 * 224 * 3);
    int pixelIndex = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < resizedImage.height; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < resizedImage.width; x++) {
        int pixel = resizedImage.getPixel(x, y);
        // Normalize pixel values to the range [-1.0, 1.0]
        inputBytes[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) - 127.5) / 127.5;
        inputBytes[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) - 127.5) / 127.5;
        inputBytes[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) - 127.5) / 127.5;
      }
    }

    // Reshape the input tensor to match the model's expected shape [1, 224, 224, 3]
    final input = inputBytes.reshape([1, 224, 224, 3]);

    // Define the output tensor shape based on your model's specifications
    final output = Float32List(1 * 4).reshape([1, 4]);

    // Run inference using the TensorFlow Lite interpreter
    _interpreter.run(input, output);

    final predictionResult = output[0] as List<double>;

    // Find the maximum element in the output
    double maxElement = predictionResult.reduce(
      (double maxElement, double element) =>
          element > maxElement ? element : maxElement,
    );

    return predictionResult;
  }

  Future<List<int>> searchForSimilarImages(
    List<List<double>> indexEmbeddings,
    List<double> queryEmbedding,
  ) async {
    try {
      final List<int> similarImages = [];
      double minDistance = double.infinity;

      // Iterate through the index embeddings and find the nearest neighbors
      for (int i = 0; i < indexEmbeddings.length; i++) {
        final List<double> indexEmbedding = indexEmbeddings[i];
        final double distance = calculateEuclideanDistance(
          queryEmbedding,
          indexEmbedding,
        );

        // Check if the current image is more similar than the previous ones
        if (distance < minDistance) {
          minDistance = distance;
          similarImages.clear();
          similarImages.add(i); // Store the index of the similar image
        } else if (distance == minDistance) {
          similarImages.add(i); // Store the index of the similar image
        }
      }

      return similarImages;
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle search errors
      print('Error during nearest-neighbor search: $e');
      throw e;
    }
  }

  double calculateEuclideanDistance(
      List<double> vector1, List<double> vector2) {
    if (vector1.length != vector2.length) {
      throw ArgumentError("Vector dimensions must match");
    }

    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.length; i++) {
      final double difference = vector1[i] - vector2[i];
      sum += difference * difference;
    }

    return sqrt(sum);
  }

  Future<List<int>> findNearestNeighbors(
    List<List<double>> indexEmbeddings,
    List<double> queryEmbedding,
  ) async {
    try {
      final List<int> similarImages = [];
      double minDistance = double.infinity;

      // Iterate through the index embeddings and find the nearest neighbors
      for (int i = 0; i < indexEmbeddings.length; i++) {
        final List<double> indexEmbedding = indexEmbeddings[i];
        final double distance = calculateEuclideanDistance(
          queryEmbedding,
          indexEmbedding,
        );

        // Check if the current image is more similar than the previous ones
        if (distance < minDistance) {
          minDistance = distance;
          similarImages.clear();
          similarImages.add(i); // Store the index of the similar image
        } else if (distance == minDistance) {
          similarImages.add(i); // Store the index of the similar image
        }
      }

      return similarImages;
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle search errors
      print('Error during nearest-neighbor search: $e');
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```